# S -> NP VP, do these sentences follow this format?

Tags: nltk

Am parsing some sentences (from the inaugural speech in the nltk corpus) with the format S -> NP VP, and I want to make sure I parsed them correctly, do these sentences follow the aforementioned format, sorry if this question seems trivial, English is not my first language. If anyone has any questions on a given sentence follows NP VP, ask me and I will give you my reasons on why I picked it and give you it's parsing tree.

```
god bless you 

our capacity remains undiminished

their memories are short

they are serious

these things are true

the capital was abandoned

they are many

god bless the united stated of
america

the enemy was advancing

all this we can do

all this we will do
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The first nine are NP VP, the last two are more complex.   The sentences we can do and we will do are NP VP, but I am not sure about the All this is strict English grammar rules...

Comment: all is a determiner, as well as this, my question is, can an NP, start with two consecutive determiners, if so then these last two sentences are NP VP as well!!

Comment: An NP can start with two consecutive determiners.  For example, the sentence "All this stuff is important".  But in those examples, the sentence is structured with part of the VP at the front, which although less common, is allowed in English grammar.  It's most normal to say "Sally will hit the ball", but it's also allowed to say "The ball, sally will hit."  Note that I used a comma there, and that's recommended.  So really, the sentences should read "All this, we will do" and "All this, we shall do".

Comment: hmm interesting...well u enlightened me, thanks again for the help (both of u guys) =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first 9 are NP VP.  In the last two, "all this" is the direct object, which is part of the VP.

```
god bless you 
NP- VP-------

our capacity remains undiminished
NP---------- VP------------------

their memories are short
NP------------ VP-------

they are serious
NP-- VP---------

these things are true
NP---------- VP------    

the capital was abandoned
NP--------- VP-----------    

they are many
NP-- VP------    

god bless the united stated of america
NP- VP--------------------------------    

the enemy was advancing
NP------- VP-----------

all this we can do
VP------ NP VP----

all this we will do
VP------ NP VP-----
```

Note that the last two sentences are semantically equivalent to the sentences "We can do all this" and "We will do all this", an order which makes the subject predicate/verb predicate breakdown easier.

Comment: yea I had doubts about the last two as well, well thanks anyways man, well at least I have the first 9 correct.